# Adjust spacing between images in figures

Tags: spacing, floats

I have a lot of plots to put in a latex document. 
I am doing multiple plots in one figure. I want to reduce the spacing between the different plots. 
Also I would like plots to arrange themselves onto multiple pages if they are larger than the space below available below the page.

[image: image space between plots]

I am using the following code:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\vspace*{-0.8cm}
\hspace{-0.3cm}
    \centering % <-- added
\begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{"Plots maxVg time/D_12-09, batch_1, d_350, T_180, XV_150, I_100-500, C_2MaxVG vs Time".png}
  \caption{Batch:1, die:350-Ta, Max\(V_{G}\) vs time, XV:150}
  \label{fig: Batch:1, die:350-Ta, MaxVG vs time, XV:150}
\end{subfigure}\hfil % <-- added
\begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{"Plots maxVg time/D_12-09, batch_1, d_350, T_180, XV_40, I_100-500, C_2MaxVG vs Time".png}
  \caption{Batch:1, die:350-Ta, Max\(V_{G}\) vs time, XV:40 T:300}
  \label{fig: Batch:1, die:350-Ta, MaxVG vs time, XV:40 T:300}
\end{subfigure}\hfil % <-- added
\medskip
\begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{"Plots maxVg time/D_13-09, batch_1, d_350, T_180, XV_40, I_100-500, C_2MaxVG vs Time".png}
  \caption{Batch:1, die:350-Ta, Max\(V_{G}\) vs time, XV:40 T:180}
  \label{fig:Batch:1, die:350-Ta, MaxVG vs time, XV:40 T:180}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{"Plots maxVg time/D_13-09, batch_3, d_250, T_300, XV_150, I_100-500, C_2MaxVG vs Time".png}
  \caption{Batch:3, die:250-SiTa, Max\(V_{G}\) vs time XV:150}
  \label{fig:Batch:3, die:250-SiTa, MaxVG vs time XV:150}
\end{subfigure}\hfil % <-- added
\medskip
\begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{"Plots maxVg time/D_13-09, batch_3, d_250, T_300, XV_40, I_100-500, C_2, N_no-time-recordingMaxVG vs Time".png}
  \caption{Batch:3, die:250-SiTa, Max\(V_{G}\) vs time XV:40}
  \label{fig:Batch:3, die:250-SiTa, MaxVG vs time XV:40}
\end{subfigure}\hfil % <-- added
\begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{"Plots maxVg time/D_13-09, batch_4, d_250, T_180, XV_40, I_100-500, C_2MaxVG vs Time".png}
  \caption{Batch:4, die:250-TaSi, Max\(V_{G}\) vs time XV:40}
  \label{fig:Batch:4, die:250-TaSi, MaxVG vs time XV:40}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Max\(V_{G}\) vs time for different samples}
\label{fig: MaxVG vs time }
\end{figure}
\FloatBarrier
```

Comment: you can place the images directly in  the document flow and have automatic page breaks where needed, or you can place them in a figure so the whole group floats together, you can not do both. You could have multiple figure environments each with a single row or two images, then latex will float then and fit as many on a page as allowed (don't use `[h!]` though as that gives latex almost no legal place to position the figures)

Comment: Is there  a good way to just beging a new page where there is a set format for images in a 2*3 configuration with little space in-between them?